# how to preserve file modification time with LFTP

Tags: ftp

I wrote a script that sync several servers at once. One of my problem is that I cannot get LFTP to preserve initial file modification time. So basically, it always upload all the files while only some changed.

Do you know how to force LFTP to preserve file modification time when downloading or uploading?

Thanks for any help.

Korchkidu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the following page

http://www.bouthors.fr/wiki/doku.php?id=en:linux:synchro_lftp

the authors state:

> When uploading, it is not possible to set the date/time on the files uploaded, that's why –>ignore-time is needed.

so if you use the flag combination --only-newer and --ignore-time you can achieve decent backup properties, in such a way that all files that differ in size are replaced. Of course it doesn't help if you really need to rely on time-synchronization but if it is just to perform a regular backup of data, it'll do the job.

Answer (score 1):

try this

from here http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html:

```
ftp:use-site-utime (boolean)
          when true, lftp sends 5-argument `SITE UTIME' command to set file modification time on
          uploaded files. Default is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to `man lftp`, I found this flag:

```
  ftp:use-mdtm-overloaded (boolean)
          when true, lftp uses two argument MDTM command to set file modification time on uploaded files. Default is false.
```

Thus, I set it to:

```
set ftp:use-mdtm-overloaded true
```

and it worked as expected.